# Navigation View Not automatically closing

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

After abit of back and forth and some good old googling I was able to get the Navigation view to work quiet well (somewhat proud of myself at this point).
I have 2 Issues (maybe connected) the primary issue is that any time I select a menu item it correctly navigates however it fails to close/minimize the menu to the left upon selecting the item.(see screenshots bellow)
The second issue (which I suspect is connected) the line of code that is supposed to automatically select the homepage when opening the app keeps throwing an exception so I removed the line.
The would be line is line 40 on Mainpage.xaml.cs and its contents would be:

```
if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "Home_Page")
```

What it looks like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysot7.png

I tried to set a variable:

```
NavView.IsPanelOpen = false;
```

but i cannot find the correct spot to place it

this is the MainPage.xaml

```
    <Page

   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:RussMenu"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
      compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    x:Class="RussMenu.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     Background="{ThemeResource 
        ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

     <Grid>

        <NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav"
        Loaded="nvTopLevelNav_Loaded"
        Margin="0,12,0,0"
        SelectionChanged="nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged"
        ItemInvoked="nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked"
        IsTabStop="False"

       >

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home"  x:Name="Nav_Home">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Home">Home</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="SaveLocal"  
     x:Name="Nav_Submit_COAQC_Results">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Submit_COAQC_Results">Submit COA/QC 
    Results</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Trim"  
        x:Name="Nav_Edit_Test_Results">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Edit_Test_Results">Edit Test 
      Results</TextBlock>
          </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="ReportHacked"  
     x:Name="Nav_Create_Claims_Ticket">
              <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Create_Claims_Ticket">Create Claims 
Ticket</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Message"  
    x:Name="Nav_Message_Page">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Message_Page">Contact 
  Leadership</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Print"  x:Name="Nav_Print_Page">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Print_Page">Print</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help"  x:Name="Nav_about">
            <TextBlock Tag="Nav_about">About</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>



    <Image Source="C:     
    Projects\Russ\RussMenu\RussMenu\Assets\Russell-Standard.jpg">  
    </Image>


    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
                   <!-- See AutoSuggestBox documentation for
                 more info about how to implement search. -->
            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="NavViewSearchBox" 
  QueryIcon="Find"/>
         </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

     </NavigationView>
   <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"   Margin="50,12,50,50"/>
  </Grid>



 </Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;


  // The Blank Page item template is documented at 
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

  namespace RussMenu
  {
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a 
  Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public string PaneDisplayMode { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()

    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void nvTopLevelNav_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // set the initial SelectedItem
        foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems)
        {

            {
                nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private void nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, 
  NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        {

        }
    }

    private void nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, 
   NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
        {
            contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage));
        }
        else
        {
            TextBlock ItemContent = args.InvokedItem as TextBlock;
            if (ItemContent != null)
            {
                switch (ItemContent.Tag)
                {

                    case "Nav_Home":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.HomePage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_about":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.About));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Message_Page":

  contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.Contact_Leadership));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Create_Claims_Ticket":

  contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.CreateClaimsTicket));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Print_Page":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.PrintPage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Submit_COAQC_Results":

  contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.submitresults));
                        break;
                    case "Nav_Edit_Test_Results":

    contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.EditTestResults));
                         break;
                }
            }

        }


           }
        }
      }
```

What it should look like.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xh8.png

and the Second issue:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FYnm.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first issue,if you want to it close/minimize the menu to the left upon selecting the item,you can add **PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"**.In addition,the frame you set should be placed inside the NavigationView. In this case, the expanded sidebar will not be masked by the textBlock.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav"
            Loaded="nvTopLevelNav_Loaded"​
            Margin="0,12,0,0"​
            SelectionChanged="nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged"​
            ItemInvoked="nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked"​
            IsTabStop="False"​
            PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"​
           >

    ...
    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"   Margin="50,12,50,50"/>​
</NavigationView>
```

About the second issus, the reason for the error is that you did not add a tag to the NavigationViewItem, but added to the textblock.So when you tried to get item.Tag,it will crash.You can correct like below.

```
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Home"  x:Name="Nav_Home" Tag="Nav_Home">
                    <TextBlock>Home</TextBlock>​
</NavigationViewItem>
```